# laravel 500 internal server error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to deploy my Laravel 4 app on 1and1 shared hosting, but I keep getting a 500 internal server error.

I have checked the following:

- Using PHP 5.4
- Mcrypt PHP extension installed
- chmod 777 /app/storage/
- Domain is pointing to /laravel/public/

I'm out of ideas now?

One thing I've noticed is if I go to /index.php/, I get a "Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required" error. Could this mean some of my paths are wrong somewhere? I doubt it, because the app is working fine locally.

Any help would be amazing.

Thanks

Comment: This is rather strange... Initially I deployed with GIT. In case something went wrong with that, I remove the entire git repo and replace it with a brand new FTP transfer of the local repo. This still gave a 500 error, but when I remove the .htaccess file in this case, the site works. If I remove .htaccess with the GIT method, I get the Fatal error above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `composer install` after cloning the repo. The vendor directory is in the Laravel `.gitignore` file by default.

Edit: just re-read your follow-up comment and realized I shouldn't attempt to answer questions after midnight.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is better than mine (I still wasn't 100% sure of the solution when I posted)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and I Did this to fix it

First: Run composer install
Second: Copy .env.example and past and rename to .env
Third: Run PHP artisan key:generate

I hope it works with you.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out being a problem with my deployment method with GIT. For some reason, my app/vendor/laravel directory and contents were not being committed and thus not pulled being pulled/cloned on my shared hosting. Really bizarre and I still do not know what was causing it.

Comment: They are not supposed be committed. This is why you have Composer.